# Finding corners of a polygon represented in a 2D array

Tags: python

I have a 2D array of 0's and 1's where the 1's represent the edges and inside of a quadrilateral, and 0's are everything outside. What is the best way to find the coordinates of the four corners?

I'm using Python so any libraries that can help are fine, but an algorithm in any language would be helpful as well.

Comment: can you print the array and edit the question

Comment: In what context does this problem arise? Will it ALWAYS be a quadrilateral?

Comment: It will ALWAYS be a quadrilateral. It essentially represents a picture of a square taken at various angles. @Eshaka, because it represents the pixels of a photo, the size of the array is in the hundreds or thousands, so it would not fit well on this page.

Comment: »Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.«

Comment: @ThomasJunk did you even read the question all the way through? I didn't do any of those things. But thanks for the downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absolutely general case (e.g. allowing for concave hulls or darn-near-triangular shapes) this will involve some uncertainty. But since you are dealing with a restricted subclass, it's easier.

You might start with kernel convolution. Consider overlapping squares of (say) 3x3 pixels: you can design a function that tells you if the center is inside (all ones), outside (all zeros), on an edge, or at a corner, based on patterns of points.

On the other hand, you could take the "convex hull" approach: the leftmost and rightmost 1-pixels are probably corners; if several appear at the same column, take the uppermost/lowermost respectively. Using the line between them, you can tell if the bulk of 1-pixels are above, below, or on both sides of the line; this tells you where to look for the other corners.

Answer (score 2):

i have an idea about how u can make a function for this by your self. according to what i understand only the for corners can have more than one "0" next to it.

if you take `array[x,y]` to be a point. `array[x-1,y],array[x+1,y],array[x,y+1],array[x,y-1]` are the 4 point close to it. you can make a loop to go through the array checking the four neighbors if the value is "1" and count the number of neighbors which has value "0". those point that has more than one(has two) neighbors with value "0" are you four corners.

Comment: This sounds like a good starting point, but remember, it's a quadrilateral, not necessarily a square so this will not always be the case.

Comment: in that case you will have to consider all the 8 neighbors. then it doesn't have to be a square

Comment: if have more than three "0"s out of eight, its a corner

Comment: I'm not sure a hard limit of 3 would work in a pixelated situation like this, but maybe the 4 pixels with the most zeroes? I'll give it a try

Comment: you can have a try.. sounds like a good idea. for a perfect shape more than 3 will work. but you know your situation more than me. good luck